# PHPMailer (forgot password) not showing any output and errors

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to program a login system wherein it has the simple forgot password feature.

I'm confused on why it does not show or echo any output but at the same time with errors.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;


require_once "functions.php";

if (isset($_POST['Email'])) {
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'capstone');

    $Email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);

    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT IDnumber FROM students WHERE 
Email='$Email'");
    if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {

        $token = generateNewString();

        $conn->query("UPDATE students SET token='$token', 
                  tokenExpire=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
                  WHERE Email='$Email'
        ");

        require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
        require_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->addAddress($Email);
        $mail->setFrom("jerrellpunsalan@yahoo.com", "CPI");
        $mail->Subject = "Reset Password";
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Body = "
            Hi,<br><br>

            In order to reset your password, please click on the link below:
```

***********

```
            Kind Regards,<br>
            My Name
        ";

        if ($Mail->send())
            exit(json_encode(array("status" => 1, "msg" => 'Please Check 
Your Email Inbox!')));
        else
            exit(json_encode(array("status" => 0, "msg" => 'Something Wrong 
Just Happened! Please try again!')));
    } else
        exit(json_encode(array("status" => 0, "msg" => 'Please Check Your 
Inputs!')));
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, 
maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Forgot Password System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px;">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" align="center">
            <img src="images/logo.png"><br><br>
            <input class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Your Email 
Address"><br>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reset 
Password">
            <br><br>
            <p id="response"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256- 
FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Email = $("#Email");

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btn-primary').on('click', function () {
            if (Email.val() != "") {
                Email.css('border', '1px solid green');

                $.ajax({
                   url: 'forgotpassword1.php',
                   method: 'POST',
                   dataType: 'json',
                   data: {
                       Email: Email.val()
                   }, success: function (response) {
                        if (!response.success)
                            $("#response").html(response.msg).css('color', 
"red");
                        else
                            $("#response").html(response.msg).css('color', 
"green");
                    }
                });
            } else
                Email.css('border', '1px solid red');
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my functions.php code:

```
<?php
function generateNewString($len = 10) {
    $token = "poiuztrewqasdfghjklmnbvcxy1234567890";
    $token = str_shuffle($token);
    $token = substr($token, 0, $len);

    return $token;
}

function redirectToLoginPage() {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: if `$mail->send()` returns FALSE - you should check the value of `$mail->ErrorInfo`.

Comment: Like Ivo said, look in `ErrorInfo`. Don't use `exit` like that. Do this instead; it's much less confusing: `echo json_encode(["status" => 1, "msg" => 'Please Check Your Email Inbox!']); exit;`. You should also be sending a `content-type: application/json` header for the JSON content.

Comment: @Synchro, I updated  "if ($Mail->send())" to " if ($mail->send())", it now echoes "Something Wrong Just Happened! Please try again!", at least it echoes something now. lol.